# Wrapping props component in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have prop 'drawerComponent' which goes in Drawer prop 'component'

This code works fine.

```js
render() {
    return(
        <Drawer component={this.props.drawerComponent} />
    )
}
```

But if I try to wrap drawerComponent by other one it fails. I get 'Element type error' or drawerComponent  is not rendering

```js
render() {

    const Wrapper = (props) => <div>{this.props.drawerComponent}</div>

    return(
        <Drawer component={() => <Wrapper drawerComponent={this.props.drawerComponent} />} />
    )
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Can you show Drawer component?

Comment: Can you show some more code like what's there in this Drawer component?

Answer (score 1):

You Drawer component accepts a component instance and not a component, you can simply write the wrapper like

```
render() {

    const Wrapper = (props) => <div>{props.drawerComponent}</div>

    return(
        <Drawer component={<Wrapper drawerComponent={this.props.drawerComponent} />} />
}
```

Comment: I get 'Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.'

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a source code. But If change drawerComponent in parent component from

const drawerComponent = () => <div></div>
to

const drawerComponent = <div></div>

my code starts working but not yours. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, no effect.